# Woocommerce Payment Gateway - I cannot get the Product ID when I have the Order ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Woocommerce Payment Gateway Plugin: I cannot get the Product ID when I have the Order ID.

On the payment page, after the cart and checkout, I have the Order ID, in this case 5648. I need to get the single product ID for the order and expected the following code to work, but I get an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on int" - is it because I'm outside the loop?:

```
        $orderid = $order->get_id();
        foreach( $orderid->get_items() as $order_item ) {
            $product = $order_item->get_product();
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            echo $product_id;
        }
```

For reference, full error message:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on int in /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-nab-dp/woocommerce-nab-dp.php:946 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WC_Gateway_NAB_Direct_Post->receipt_page(5648) #1 /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/STAR-child/woocommerce/checkout/order-receipt.php(44): do_action('woocommerce_rec...', 5648) #4 /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/customer/...') #5 /home/customer/www/ in /home/customer/www/xyz.com/public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-nab-dp/woocommerce-nab-dp.php on line 946"

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is because you are calling `get_items()` on `orderId` instead of `order` (`Call to a member function get_items() on int`). I'm not sure about rest of code.

```
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {
...
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Matin. The original first two lines of code were "$order = $order->get_id();
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {" and I changed the $order variable to $orderid for clarity. Even if I change it back, I still get the error. Maybe I haven't understood?

Comment: Is the error message the same, if you are getting the items with `$order->get_items()`? It really shouldn't be, because `$order` should never be an integer. Even `wc_get_order` returns either boolean, or WC_Order object. Double check the error message, if it is the same, perhaps you only have order ID, but not it's object, in that case set the order variable like this: `$order = wc_get_order($order_id)`.